# How to convert datetime to "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I need send data datetime to API. But I don't convert to format of datetime same below

```
  "created_at": "2014-05-28T21: 38: 51.720986+11: 00",
  "date_of_birth": "1994-05-28T00: 00: 00+11: 00",
```

Please help me. convert on PHP language

Comment: unsurprisingly the function you want is called `date()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: You've got an actual datetime object? http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: Downvote for accepting wrong answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@DanielW comments, use

> For future readers, here is the working format: `Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vO`
> **(without colon in timezone)** and `Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP` **(with colon in
> timezone)**.

**use**

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s.uZ', strtotime($created_at_input)); // yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ
date('c', strtotime($date_of_birth_input)); // yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+00:00
```

**eg:**

```
echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vO', strtotime('2011-02-01 00:00:00')); // 2011-02-01T00:00:00.000+0000
echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP', strtotime('2011-02-01 00:00:00')); // 2011-02-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s.uP', strtotime('2011-02-01 00:00:00')); // 2011-02-01 00:00:00.000000+05:30

echo date(DATE_ATOM, strtotime('2011-02-01 00:00:00')); // 2011-02-01T00:00:00+05:30

echo date('c', strtotime('2011-02-01 00:00:00')); // 2011-02-01T00:00:00+05:30
```

<strike>Try</strike>

use `date('c', strtotime($date_of_birth_input));`

eg:

```
echo date('c', strtotime('2011-02-01 00:00:00')); //ouput: 2011-02-01T00:00:00+00:00
```

see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: This format is different from the format in question: You are missing the milliseconds. Coming from Google to this answer is disappointing.

Comment: @DanielW. Thank you for pointing my mistake

Comment: It's still wrong. For future readers, here is the working format: `Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vO` (without colon in timezone) and `Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP` (with colon in timezone).

Comment: How to convert in to the below format

2015-10-17T00:00:00.000Z