# Which date format is this?

Tags: php, date, datetime, datetime-format

I want to convert this date-time string `2022-09-30T21:39:25.220185674Z` to `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` but it returns 1970-01-01 01:00:00 everytime.

Tried with: `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2022-09-30T21:39:25.220185674Z'));` or `date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', strtotime('2022-09-30T21:39:25.220185674Z'));`

Can you help find out which format this is and how i could corretly format such string in PHP?

Went through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390784/how-to-format-an-utc-date-to-use-the-z-zulu-zone-designator-in-php) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443125/how-to-convert-datetime-to-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-sssz-in-php) couldn't help.

Comment: It’s not about formatting it out, it’s about `strtotime` not knowing how to parse it. You need to use another method to parse it

Comment: Which method can you recommend? Datetime doesn't seem to work neither

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a ISO 8601 datetime string with microseconds, where `Z` is the timezone *"Zulu"* or `UTC + 0 hours`.

ISO 8601 can be parsed with `DateTime()` like this:

```
$string = '2022-09-30T21:39:25.220185Z';
  //create DateTime object
$date   = date_create_from_format( "Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP" , $string);
echo $date->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u' );
```

**However** This will not work with your string, as the `u` parameter in the format `"Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP"` which represents the microseconds, in PHP takes a **maximum** of `6 digits`, and yours has `9`.

You can resolve this by removing all above 6 digits from the microseconds part of the string with a regex, like

```
$string = '2022-09-30T21:39:25.220185674Z';
$new_string = preg_replace( '/^.*?\.\d{0,6}\K\d*/' , '' , $string );
$date   = date_create_from_format( "Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP" , $new_string );
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');
```

Output: `2022-09-30 21:39:25.220180`

The regex explained:

```
1. ^.*?\.\d{0,6} // select from the begin everything including the dot
                 // and max 6 digits
2. \K            // forget the previous match and start again from the 
                 // point where 1. ended
3. \d*           // select all digits left
4. replace the match with ""
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution worked. I had just to use ```date_format($string 'Y-m-d H:i:s');``` afterward to get the correct format

Answer (score 1):

With '?' in the format, all digits after the 6th digit can be cut off.

```
$string = '2022-09-30T21:39:25.220185123Z';
$date   = date_create_from_format( "Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u???P" , $string);
var_dump($date);
```

https://3v4l.org/Upm6v

As of PHP version 8.0.10, strings like '2022-09-30T21:39:25.220185674Z' are recognized by DateTime without any problems.

```
$str = '2022-09-30T21:39:25.220185674Z';
$d = new DateTime($str);
var_dump($d);
/*
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2022-09-30 21:39:25.220185"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(2)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(1) "Z"
}
*/
```

https://3v4l.org/pI4kO

Comment: I'm not using PHP 8, still on v7.4

Comment: I've added a variant for PHP7 to my answer.