# Convert "Zulu" or UTC time with Carbon and Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

Working with API which gives me datetime in "2022-11-02T21:00:00.0000000Z" format.
I am trying to convert it using Carbon and throwing me an error.

```
$dateTime = "2022-11-02T21:00:00.0000000Z";
$dateUpdated =  Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', $dateTime);
```

Error from Carbon:

```
Error Parsing updated datetime with format Y-m-d\TH:i:s Carbon\Exceptions\InvalidFormatException: Trailing data in /usr/src/app/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Traits/Creator.php:676
```

I am using Laravel 8.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which date format is this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73915867/which-date-format-is-this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use `Carbon::parse`

```
$dateTime = "2022-11-02T21:00:00.0000000Z";
$dateUpdated =  Carbon::parse($dateTime);
echo $dateUpdated ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```